# How to get Devexpress LookupEdit Value Member Value?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

Hi Im using devexpress .
I want to know how to get the value member value in lookupEdit.
I set the DisplayMember as prior to SupplierName
And ValueMember to SupplierID

The code below displays both and SupplierName as the text in lookupedit..
what I want is to keep the SupplierName as the Display but I want to get the supplierID when saving it to database

Scenario:

> I want the value of the Supplier ID for example 001 - Supplier1 The
>   display text in the look up is Supplier1 what I want is the 001

```
 Private Function LoadSupplierData()
    Dim bResult As Boolean
    Dim SQLcmd As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    SQLcmd.AppendLine("SELECT SupplierID,SupplierName ")
    SQLcmd.AppendLine("FROM Supplier ")
    SQLcmd.AppendLine("WHERE Status='Active'")
    Try
        Using SQLconnect As New SqlConnection(g_constring)
            Using SQLadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLcmd.ToString, SQLconnect)
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                SQLadapter.Fill(ds, "SupplierDetails")
                Dim dvm As DataViewManager = New DataViewManager(ds)
                dvMain = dvm.CreateDataView(ds.Tables("SupplierDetails"))
            End Using
        End Using
        txtSupplier.Properties.DataSource = dvMain
     Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.Trim, "Error in database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        bResult = False
    End Try
    Return bResult
End Function
```

Comment: you want the value from the selected row in the lookup?

Comment: no I want the value of the Supplier ID for example 001 - Supplier1       The display text in the look up is Supplier1 what I want is the 001.. is that possible?

Comment: yes it's possible, if you set the ValueMember to SupplierID then this is how it is.

Comment: Iv'e already set the value member to SupplierID but I cant get the value ..can you show me some code on how to get the value of the value member ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the selected value you could simply do txtSupplier.EditValue